# Moving NUnit/ReSharper tests to Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

We have a WinForms application that we're planning to port to Silverlight. Obviously the UI will need to be totally rewritten, but we have a lot of business logic that's well-tested with [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) tests. We use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to run the tests inside the IDE, and nunit-console to run the tests on the continuous integration machines.

As we start moving our business-logic classes into Silverlight assemblies, how do we get these unit tests to run against those Silverlight assemblies? My understanding is that NUnit can't run Silverlight tests without [significant tweaking](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2008/05/01/silverlight-nunit-projects.aspx), and said tweaking (in the form of a project template) appears to be VS2008- and Silverlight 3-specific (we'll most likely be using VS2010 and Silverlight 4 for our port).

We can move our tests to another testing framework if that's the best option, but there doesn't seem to be much else besides NUnit. The [Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut/) looks like it runs inside the browser, which is a non-starter for continuous integration.

I'm aware that [Silverlight 4.0 assemblies can be loaded into a .NET 4.0 executable](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/12/Silverlight-CLR-Interopt), but I'm unsure of what this means for unit testing. Would it work to compile our business-logic assembly as a Silverlight 4.0 DLL, and write a full-framework .NET 4.0 NUnit test assembly that references the Silverlight DLL? It seems like this might work, but has anyone done this successfully with unit tests?

Bottom line, **what should we do for our unit tests?** We need a solution that

- still lets us run tests in the ReSharper test runner;
- can also be run from the command line;
- works in VS2010.

We don't instantiate any UI objects in our tests, so those pesky DependencyObject threading issues aren't a concern. We just need to test our Silverlight business logic.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if NUnit is supported or how difficult it would be to add, but you might check out http://AGunit.codeplex.com for ReSharper Silverlight support.

I wrote a little tool to C.I. silverlight tests and attempt to help in normal dev/tdd scenarios - you can go check out http://StatLight.codeplex.com.

You should be able to find an NUnit build for silverlight out there (there's a few). Not sure of any runners that work with NUnit in the browser. However StatLight can run some basic NUnit functionality for you.

Hope this gives you a little help.